# how to create a simple javascript or jquery function in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm just trying to create a simple javascript function in codeigniter, which is called onclick of a radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="<?php echo $plan['amount']; ?>" onclick="fn()" />
```

and the javascript function is follows

```
<?php $this->load->library('javascript/jquery');?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function fn()
        {
            alert("sdg");
        }


</script>
```

please tell me how to solve this problem ?

**EDIT :**
The problem is that I'm not able to call the function. it is not working onclick of radio button.

Comment: And whats the problem.? Is there any error.?

Comment: what is the error/ output?

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 -- please read the question again. i have updated it

Comment: Could be the order of loading ? First you should send the input element and only afterwards send the script .

Comment: @Joel_Blum --- i have tried placing it at all the places. but it doesn't works.

Comment: 1st Check for any errors in the browser console log . Also please provide the whole php script .

Comment: @Paul --- tried that even.

Comment: Read this article http://ggnome.com/wiki/Using_The_Browser_Error_Console

Comment: @Pankaj are you placed your javascript code within the same page or it is from external js file?

Answer (score 0):

```
**This Code is working..........**
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function getValue()
        {
            alert("sdg");
        }


</script>
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="<?php echo $plan['amount']; ?>" onclick="javascript: getValue();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

Actually it was the problem with the placement of script.
I tried changing the position of script, and then finally it worked at last.
Although i couldn't found the real cause. but it was the position of script, that was creating problem.

Thanks a lot all of you to answer this question.